# how to check for properties in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am making a service call where I get back some data. For example:

```
var response = [
  {id: 1, name: 'text1'},
  {id: 2, name: 'text2'}
];
```

This array represents the most possible data I could get back. In other instances I may get back an empty array, an array with only one of those objects(either or of the objects inside the array). 
I'd like to somehow loop through my array and check the id of each on=bject to set a flag for the front end to display other data. How do I properly do checks for the id's in the array for the scenarios I mentioned above?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
var response = [{ id: 1, name: "text1" }, { id: 2, name: "text2" }];

var exists = (id, arr) => arr.some(e => e.id === id);

var id1Exists = exists(1, response);
var id2Exists = exists(2, response);
var id3Exists = exists(3, response);

console.log({ id1Exists, id2Exists, id3Exists });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var response = [
  {id: 1, name: 'text1'},
  {id: 2, name: 'text2'}
];
let flag 
response.length > 0 && response.forEach(el => {
 // JUST CHECKING IF ID IS PRESENT AND EQUAL TO 1
// YOU CAN CHANGE ACCORDINGLY
 flag = el.id && el.id === 1 ? true : false
})

console.log(flag)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here I write a function to find a certain object inside your array, I think this must help you:

```
public function getMyId($myArray, $id)
    {
      foreach($myArray as $key => $element){
       $arrayFromObject = (Array) $element;
         foreach($arrayFromObject as $keyObject => $valueObject){
           if($valueObject['id'] == $id)
             {
                 return $myArray[$key]->$keyObject;
             }
         }
      }
      return null;
    }
```

For each element inside your array I convert object to array to  verify if its id is equal to id u're looking for, than I return the array at certain position and certain value, or if you prefer u could just return the $valueObject it will be an array. I hope help u;

Comment: Not `php`, He asked Javascript question

Comment: true, I didn't see sorry;